# ¿Qué significa exactamente "acretar"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, significado, ciencia, neologismos

Leo en un titular de [una publicación científica](http://www.astrofisicayfisica.com/2010/04/estrellas-de-neutrones-podrian-acretar.html):

> Estrellas de neutrones podrían acretar materia oscura hasta convertirse en agujeros negros

Entiendo que el verbo tiene que ver con el término *[acreción](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0aqcwO5)*, recogido por el DLE con el significado de "crecimiento por adición de materia". Sin embargo, el DLE no recoge la voz *acretar*, aunque por el contexto entiendo que significa lo mismo que *[absorber](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0CjIsyE)*.

Entiendo que debe de haber alguna sutil diferencia entre *absorber* y *acretar*. Por tanto, ¿qué significa exactamente *acretar*? ¿En qué se diferencia de *absorber*? En caso de haber diferencias, ¿existe alguna alternativa en el DLE cuyo significado se asemeje más al de *acrecer*? Y por último, *acreción* viene del latín *accretio*, pero ¿y *acretar*? ¿Cómo ha llegado al español?

Comment: Es una traducción de "accrete", verbo correspondiente a ["accretion"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accretion_(astrophysics)), pero no tenía ni idea de que se hubiera traducido así.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yo creo que absorber no es exactamente lo mismo:

> [**absorber**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0CjIsyE)
>
> 1. tr. Dicho de una sustancia sólida o de un líquido: Atraer y retener, respectivamente, un líquido o un gas o vapor.

Se absorbe un líquido o un gas pero no sólidos.

En todo caso acretar podría ser añadir:

> [**añadir**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=30pOaVr)
>
> 1. tr. Agregar, incorporar algo a otra cosa.
> 2. tr. Aumentar, acrecentar, ampliar.

O incorporar:

> [**incorporar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LJZZNZJ)
>
> 1. tr. Unir una persona o una cosa a otra u otras para que haga un todo con ellas.

En el glosario de astronomía.com dicen de [acreción](http://www.astromia.com/glosario/acrecion.htm):

> Es la agregación de materia a un cuerpo. Por ejemplo, la acreción de
>   masa por una estrella es la adición de masa a la estrella a partir de
>   materia interestelar o de una compañera.

El verbo acretar no lo encuentro en ningún diccionario, yo personalmente usaría *incorporar* en la frase del ejemplo:

> *Estrellas de neutrones podrían **incorporar** materia oscura hasta
>   convertirse en agujeros negros*

---

En la web de la [sociedad astronómica española](http://www.sea-astronomia.es/drupal/) hay un artículo interesante que habla del tema. [Aquí](http://www.sea-astronomia.es/drupal/sites/default/files/archivos/descubre/AstronomiA%20156%20-%20TERMINOLOGIA%20ASTRONOMICA%20-%20JUNIO%202012.pdf) el original en PDF.

Recojo un par de fragmentos del artículo:

> Para este proceso en muchas lenguas se usa un término derivado del
>   latín *accretio*, que significa «crecimiento» o «aumento». La comisión
>   ha detectado dos alternativas en castellano para este concepto:
>   *acreción* y *acrecimiento*. Tradicionalmente solo constaba en el
>   Diccionario de la Real Academia *acrecimiento*, derivado natural del
>   verbo *acrecer*, que la RAE define como «hacer mayor, aumentar», si bien
>   se trata de un término de uso sobre todo legal. Por otra parte,
>   *acreción* ha sido muy utilizado en astronomía y otras disciplinas, como
>   geología, meteorología o biología, para procesos de crecimiento por
>   añadido de partículas pequeñas.
>
> ---
>
> Mientras que lo formalmente correcto sería *acrecer*, a veces se
>   encuentra *acretar*, pero en ambos casos las dudas sobre la corrección
>   formal, el significado o la transitividad de los verbos hacen
>   aconsejable evitarlos, a favor de giros no demasiado complicados como
>   «incorporar materia», «acumular gas», «agregar fragmentos», o
>   similares

Answer (score 3):

Aun cuando fuera un verbo real, creo que está mal usado. En el ejemplo, se usa "*acretar*" de manera similar a "acumular", pero usarlo así traiciona el significado de "acreción".

Tenemos claro que "acreción" significa:

> [**acreción**](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=acreci%C3%B3n).
>
> 1. f. Crecimiento por adición de materia, como en los depósitos minerales o los continentes.

Ahroa bien, si definimos "acreción" como:

> ? **acreción**.
>
> 1. f. Acción y efecto de **acretar**.

Y movemos la carga semántica al verbo, entonces "*acretar*" significaría:

> ? **acretar**.
>
> 1. intr. Crecer una cosa por adición de materia.

Y **sería un verbo intransitivo** a todas luces, igual que el propio verbo "*[crecer](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=crecer)*" en el que se basa.

No sería válido decir entonces:

> Las estrellas podrían acretar Ⓧmateria oscura

Porque "materia oscura" no puede actuar como objeto directo: tiene que ir como [complemento circunstancial](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_circunstancial) de modo o de instrumento.
Lo correcto (suponiendo que fuese un verbo real, cosa que no es) sería:

> Las estrellas podrían acretar *usando* materia oscura.
> Las estrellas podrían acretar *mediante* materia oscura.
> Las estrellas podrían acretar *gracias a* la materia oscura.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. En los textos de astronomía en inglés siempre se usa el término [accretion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accretion_(astrophysics)) como **the accumulation of particles into a massive object by gravitationally attracting more matter** y el que escribió el articulo se inventó el verbo cuando pudo haber simplemente usado **acumulan materia oscura hasta convertirse en agujeros negros**